# Where do you store the received tokens in your OpenID-connect client?

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect

I am looking for advice around where to store the received tokens in an OpenIDConnect client.

In an OpenIDConnect client, you can always set the **SaveTokens** to true, to store all your tokens in the cookie itself. But the drawback is that we all know that the Cookie size grows quite bit when you keep your ID, access and refresh tokens.

My question is what do **you** do with your tokens in your clients? Do you store them somewhere else? In a database? in memory? or just stick them in the cookie and live with the huge cookie size?

My second question, are there any ready made code/libraries to keep the tokens in a database or elsewhere? My main issue is to make sure that I don't loose my tokens and users when I redeploy or restart my application.

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    options.Authority = "https://localhost:6001";
    options.Scope.Clear();
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.Scope.Add("profile");

    options.SaveTokens = true;
    ...
```

Comment: It really depends on how long you want to store them. DB is permanent, cookie is temporary. In-memory cache is pretty useful in certain scenarios. It also means you can't ever go over the 4096 bytes size limit for cookies.

Comment: I need to store them in some persistent way so that I don't loose the tokens and that my users are not kicked out when I redeploy. I could try to create some token cache my self, but I hope not having to reimplement that my self... but also to learn how other handles their tokens.

Comment: Understood. I basically told you how I do it. For me it depends on how long I want to store them. I develop web API's mostly though. I would imagine that for desktop apps I'd want to either use a local db or maybe even a "temporary" file to persist them to. Or isolated storage if it's a progressive web app you can "install" to your desktop.

Comment: Thanks for your input, for me my usecase is classic web-aplications where I want to keep the tokens as long as they are intended to live (like weeks for the refresh tokens). ( If you use ASP.NET Core you can have tokens that is larger than 4000 (it automatically split it up in multiple session tokens)  but think that is a bad idea for many reasons.